# How to resove Android resource compliation error gotten while rebuilding project

Tags: android

I clicked on rebuild project after a while I got error; android resource compilation failed it pop out a window asking to select an encoding to open audio file. This error screen kept persisting despite all my effort

I have done invalidate cache and restart, rebuild project, deleted files in app data\local\Google\AndroidStudio x.y\system\caches, clean and rebuild, etc all these didn't work.

See my screenshot for more detail.

[image]

**Error Logs**

```
Task :app:mergeDebugResources
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource compilation failed","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\Joseph\\AndroidStudioProjects\\AudioApp\\app\\src\\main\\res\\raw\\tune_3.midi"}],"original":"C:\\Users\\Joseph\\AndroidStudioProjects\\AudioApp\\app\\src\\main\\res\\raw\\tune_3.midi: AAPT: error: failed to open file .\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource compilation failed","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\Joseph\\AndroidStudioProjects\\AudioApp\\app\\src\\main\\res\\raw\\tune_3.midi"}],"original":"C:\\Users\\Joseph\\AndroidStudioProjects\\AudioApp\\app\\src\\main\\res\\raw\\tune_3.midi: AAPT: error: file failed to compile.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}

> Task :app:mergeDebugResources FAILED
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > Android resource compilation failed
     C:\Users\Joseph\AndroidStudioProjects\AudioApp\app\src\main\res\raw\tune_3.midi: AAPT: error: failed to open file .
```

Comment: Please post errors as text. For example, we cannot read the entire error message, as it is scrolled off the side of your IDE.

Comment: Please check your file extension properly in RAW and Drawable files it is not supported by IDE

Comment: This app is a two year old app and the raw files have been there without being tempered with. All audio extension ended with either mid, amr, midi or mp3

Comment: Is there anything I can do?